# thread Lock on Custom Thread python

Tags: python

Can someone tell me where i can put the lock inside a custom thread in python?

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,lock):
        super(WorkerThread,self).__init__()
        self.lock = lock
    def run(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        print "Hello World"
        self.lock.release()


worker = WorkerThread(lock)
```

Error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<buffer>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<buffer>", line 11, in __init__
AssertionError: release() of un-acquire()d lock
```

Comment: You can make your life a touch easier (and safer in the general case) by using the lock as a context manager. You can replace acquire and release with `with self.lock:` and everything indented under that block is run whilst the lock is acquired and it is released when the block ends.

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. Most of the definition of `run` is actually nested inside `__init__`, and the `self.lock.release()` is actually outside `run` and inside `__init__`. Your thread ends up trying to release the unlocked lock on thread creation.

Don't mix tabs and spaces. Stick to spaces. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor to make the problem more visible, and get a better editor if your editor can't do that. Running Python with the `-tt` flag can also help catch these errors.